# How to show only the deepest taxonomy term in a drupal view, having used hierarchical select to tag content

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, taxonomy

I have a site for sporting products. 
I use hierarchical select to tag the products that are added to the site - and the term lineage is saved, so Taxonomy menu automatically creates nice hierarchical menus linking to the taxonomy pages - which I've overridden using views.

See here for an example:  http://dayalssports.com/product-menu/badminton/rackets

The rackets are grouped according to taxonomy term. 
Problem is, as the term lineage is saved, the taxonomy view displays all the terms, in a seemingly random order. It doesn't display them parent->Child1->Child2 etc as you would expect.

I want to display only the deepest term. So instead of having:

***Rackets > Y Series Rackets > Badminton***

which is out of order anyway, I just get

***Y Series Rackets***

Is there a way to do this? Or is there at least a way to order them correctly?

By the way - the **>** character between terms isn't the default separator, I just set it to that as I thought the terms would be displayed in order. As they're not, it looks a bit stupid, as it gives the impression of hierarchy. The hierarchy is actually

***Badminton > Rackets > Y Series Rackets***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function theme_hs_taxonomy_formatter_lineage($variables) {
  $output = '';
  $lineage = $variables['lineage'];
  $separator = theme('hierarchical_select_item_separator');

  // Render each item within a lineage.
  $items = array();
  foreach ($lineage as $level => $item ) {
    dpm($item);
    $line  = '<span class="lineage-item lineage-item-level-' . $level . '">';
    $line .= drupal_render($item);
    //this adds a flag link to every term, not just the last term
    if(!count(taxonomy_get_children($item['#options']['entity']->tid))){
      $line .= flag_create_link('hobbies_and_interests', $item['#options']['entity']->tid);
    }

    $line .= '</span>';
    $items[] = $line;
  }
  $output .= implode($separator, $items);
  return $output;
}
```

Reference : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58691/how-can-i-show-a-flag-link-only-for-the-deepest-terms-for-a-field-with-multipl

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my php skills are very limited, can you suggest what I need to do to the above code so that only the last term is displayed? I don't need the flag part, just for the output to return the term with the highest level value. Thanks.